# I want to create a whatsapp share link with multiple pdf links that shows single word hyperlinks on the message

Tags: hyperlink, share, whatsapp

can someone please advice me on how I can display hyperlink words instead of the full pdf links on my whatsApp share text field, I have started with this:

```
https://wa.me/?text=Aqua-Right%203%20https://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_Label-1.pdf, http://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_SDS-1.pdf, http://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Aqua-Right_Range_Eng_Pamphlet.pdf
```

This link needs to look like this when you send it to someone:
Aqua-Right 3 [Label](https://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_Label-1.pdf), [SDS](http://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_SDS-1.pdf), [Pamphlet](http://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Aqua-Right_Range_Eng_Pamphlet.pdf)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

These are three different links and you need to treat a link using the `<a>` tag.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) for the detail but your code will look like:

```
<a href="https://wa.me/?text=Aqua-Right%203%20https://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_Label-1.pdf">Label</a>
<a href="https://wa.me/?text=Aqua-Right%203%20http://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_SDS-1.pdf>SDS</a>
<a href="https://wa.me/?text=Aqua-Right%203%20http://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Aqua-Right_Range_Eng_Pamphlet.pdf>Pamphlet</a>
```

This is completely untested on what the link itself will do but is the right syntax to display a link on a webpage

Comment: Thank you Lelio for your advice and yes this is correct but it is still showing me this message as the full link and not the word hyperlink: Aqua-Right 3 https://rolfesagri.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Aqua_Right_3_Label-1.pdf